# Android Activity as library

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, aar

I'm stating a android project which I would like to structure into plugins.

To test the plugin structure I created a new project in android studio with a empty activity. I changed the displayed text to "Hello plugin" just to be able to identify the activity. I also added a log output to the on create method.
This project was then exported as a android library (.aar)

I created a second project (also default empty activity project), which would then represent the actual app. I imported the library and launched the libraries activity using a intent. nothing more and nothing less!

My problem now is if I launch the app the "Hello world" text from the actual app is displayed and not the "Hello plugin" from the activity that is being launched. The strange thing is tat I don't get any error and the log output from the libraries activity onCreate method appears in the LogCat!

Is there something special I have to do in order to be able to call a activity from a library, am I not allowed to do it at all or am I just missing something essential?

Thanks, 
FallenRiteMonk

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by my self!
It was a resource conflict problem. Adding a prefix to libraries string resources solved the problem!